# Load data of PHP file in to textarea with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a file called `Getsocks.php` this file contain this code:

```
<?
    session_start();
    require("../includes/config.php");
    $getsocks = mysqli_query($cl,"SELECT * FROM getsocks");
    while($socks = mysqli_fetch_array($getsocks))
    {
        echo $socks['socks']."<br />";
    }
?>
```

When this file is executed I get only `socks` values nothing else. Can anyone tell me how I can send a request by AJAX to that file and grab the values into a `textarea`?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest example with no additional settings:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Getsocks.php'
}).done(function(data) {
    $("#myTextarea").html(data);
});
```

Refer to [jQuery AJAX documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the name of your `textarea` is `something`.

```
<textarea id="something" name="something"></textarea>
```

Run an AJAX request and fetch details from your file
**Javascript**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'GetSocks.php',
        success: function(response)
        {
            $("#something").val(response);
        }
    })
})
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?
    session_start();
    require("../includes/config.php");
    $getsocks = mysqli_query($cl,"SELECT * FROM getsocks");
    while($socks = mysqli_fetch_array($getsocks))
    {
        echo $socks['socks']."<br />";
    }
?>
```